# Removing rows in a column if the same rows in another column are blank using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I am having trouble trying to remove certain rows in a column if the same rows on another are empty. I really don't know what kind of code to use for this and would appreciate you help.

[image]

Basically since L26:L32 are empty, I want to remove G26:G32. I want this code to run for all of columns G and L, so that if there are any blanks in cell L then the cell in the same row in column G should be deleted. Please ask any questions you have. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to delete just the cell in column G or the whole row?

Comment: Just the cells in column G, that have an empty cell in column L in the same row, should be deleted. So in this example, Huntsman from G26:G32 should be deleted since there are blanks in L26:L32.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub DeleteMatchingCells()
    Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
    For row = 1 To 1000 ' I picked this limit arbitrarily, use your max row number
        ' Here we check if the cell in column L has content
        If Cells(row, 12) = "" Then
            ' If it doesn't, we set col G to nothing
            Cells(row, 7) = ""
        End If
    Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how I could delete the entire row if there is a blank cell in column L? So if it's -1 then keep the row, but if it's blank then delete the entire row? Thanks.

Comment: It is possible, but you have to be careful, since you'll be deleting rows while iterating over them and the numbering gets messed up.  And you can't undo it if you make a mistake because it's VBA.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786727/how-to-delete-entire-row-in-excel-if-a-cell-contains-a-specific-value)

Comment: Do you think it would be better off just to hide the rows or does it not make a difference